# Show input field on change selected value in Select2 yii2

Tags: jquery, postgresql, yii2, jquery-select2, selected

Here's my form code.

```
    <?=$form->field($model, 'role_id')->widget(Select2::classname(),
            [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(RoleUser::find()->all(),'id','name'),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Role'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    // 'minimumInputLength' => 1,
                ],
            ]);
        ?>

        <?=$form->field($model, 'group')->widget(Select2::classname(),
            [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Group::find()->all(),'group','group_name'),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Group 1'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'minimumInputLength' => 1,
                ],
            ]);
        ?>
        <div id="group2">
        <?=$form->field($model, 'group_id2')->widget(Select2::classname(),
            [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Group::find()->all(),'group_id','group_name'),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Toko 2'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'minimumInputLength' => 1,
                ],
            ]);
        ?>
    </div>           
        <div id="group3">
        <?=$form->field($model, 'group_id3')->widget(Select2::classname(),
            [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Group::find()->all(),'group_id','group_name'),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Toko 3'],
                'id' => 'group_name3',
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'minimumInputLength' => 1,
                ],
            ]);
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    $script = <<< JS

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#email').focus();


    $('#group2').hide();
    $('#group3').hide();

    $('#s2id_register-form-role_id').on('change',function(){ // name is the id of select-box 
    if($(this).val() == 'admin_group'){ // check selected value is equal to admin_group 
    $('#group2, #group3').show();
    } // if yes then show both div 
    });
});

    JS;
    $this->registerJs($script);
    ?>
```

I want to show input form group 2 and group 3 if only selected value on role_user is admin_group. 
So in the defaut form, it should be only show role_user and group1 form. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

I have editted that the javascript. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: initially `display:none;` for `form group 2 and group 3` and then using jquery show them

Comment: @AlivetoDie i don't have any idea how to show group2 and group3 after change the role user value

Comment: You can do it like something like this:-

    `$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#name').on('change',function(){ // name is the id of select-box
         if($(this).val() =='admin_group'){ // check selected value is equal to admin_group
            $('#group2, #group3').show(); // if yes then show both div
         }
      });
    });`

Comment: @AlivetoDie i've change javascript but it still doest work. Group2 and group3 still don't show when i set the role user is admin_group. Thanks.

Comment: you need to show the exact html which is rendered on your browser, because this code snippet it's hard to find out  what id's for each section is there and how to hide them.BTW did you add jQuery library before the script code i have given to you in comments?

Comment: Yes, i've added JQuery library. But it still doesn't work

Comment: As  i said that you have to show the rendered html not the code you shown. We can't help with this code structure. We need the final rendered html.